# Run bash script on network changes

Tags: bash, ubuntu, network-interface

How can I set Ubuntu to run a bash when network changes. Like changing local IP, connecting VPNs, disconnect one interface and connect to another.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection ?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek quite possibly, but we don't tag cross-site duplicates. You'd be welcome to create your own answer and cross-reference that one as your source.

Comment: This answer worked: [How to run a script, depending on internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/258585/859739)

Comment: @TiTAN : the idea would now be to give good answers some points, by clicking on the "up" flag, that is the recompense for answering your question...

Answer (score 0):

See my `net-o-matic` script at https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic . It watches for connection going down and does a user- specified Thing.